# Initialize Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getDatabase,
} from "firebase/database";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain:
    "XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseUrl:
    "https://XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX",
  storageBucket:
    "XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
  appId:
    "1:AAAAAAAAAAAA:web:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXX",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(
  firebaseConfig
);
const db = getDatabase();
```

When running my code, Firebase kindly tells me the following:

> [2022-11-23T22:45:42.778Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app (https://XXXXXXX-XX-XXXXX-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)

I as a friend of order reads the outputed message and CHANGES the databaseUrl in my code as the one STATED by Firebase in above message.

I then run my code again and get the SAME message. What am I doing wrong?